# Not Operation on Unsigned Int in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

So I now `~n` gives me the not operation on the integer n, but is there any way I can read this as an unsigned int?

For example `~50`, I get `-51`, when I actually want `13`. Is there any way to do this in Java?

So for example, 50 in binary is `110010`. When the digits are inverted, we should get `001101`.

Comment: Could you explain how `~50` would result in `13`? In unsigned conversion, `~50` should result in `4294967245`

Comment: @Turing85 Edited the comment. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You neglect the leading digits. An `int` has 32 bit, thus all 26 leading zeros  of `50 `will be flipped to `1` as well, resulting in `4294967245 `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the leading zero bits unchanged, you can set them to zero after the 'binary not' operation. All we need is to create the `11...1` mask with the number of 1's equal to the number of significant bits in `n`, then we can set to zero all other bits:

```
int invert(int n) {
    int mask = (Integer.highestOneBit(n) << 1) - 1;
    return (~n & mask);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 32 bits, and all those leasing zeroes become ones.

```
int mask = Integer.highestOneBit(n) << 1:
return ~n & - - mask;
```